# Blow up meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Father bought me a monkey from the bazaar. Not a real one but the kind you have to **blow up**. It was brown and had a bow tie.*

What does "blow up" mean here?

Comment: inflate, Blow up is the same here as blowing up a balloon, with your breath; or inflating a bicycle/ car tyre.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To blow up is to inflate. Put air into.